# Finding correct IP Address

Tags: apache, networking, ip-address

I have suspicion to believe that Google is not telling me the correct public IP address of my machine. The reason being is because I did a Google Search of "What's my IP" and it returned an IP address. However whenever I try to use that IP address when necessary, it does not work. (For example: http:///pathtofile). Another reason is because when i performed the same search on my smart phone, it produced the same exact ip address. When I performed the search over network from my phone, I got the correct ip address of my smart phone. From what I know of ip addresses, no two devices should have the same address since that is how the Internet "identifies" your machine. So from these 3 experiences I have concluded that Google is not telling me my IP address, rather the ip address given to me by my wireless router. How can I find the correct public ip address for my machine?

Comment: "No two devices should have the same address" is not correct. Ever heard of NAT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google will be telling you the public IP address of your router, not the IP address of your computer/device. All traffic is routed through your router and Google sends the traffic back to your router. The router then determines the device which made the request and routes the packet to that device. 
What are you trying to acheive? If you are just seeing if your web server is running you can use `http:/127.0.0.1` or `http://localhost` 
If you are trying to find your internal ip then run ifconfig (in Linux) or ipconfig (in Windows) and it will display it for you.